# Gunicorn Socket file is missing

Tags: django, sockets, unix, nginx, gunicorn

I am running a Django project and I want Gunicorn and Nginx to serve this project.
I am using Gunicorn 19.5.

The problem is basically that my socket file doesn't get created and I tried everything (chmod 777, chown, ...) and nothing is working.

Here is my bash script to start gunicorn:

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME="hello_project" # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/home/ubuntu/git/hello_project # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/home/ubuntu/git/hello_project/run/gunicorn.sock # we will communicte using this unix socket
LOG_FILE=/home/ubuntu/git/hello_project/logs/gunicorn.log

USER=ubuntu # the user to run as
GROUP=ubuntu # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3 # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn

MAX_REQUESTS=1 # reload the application server for each request
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=hello_project.settings # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=hello_project.wsgi # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ~/.virtualenvs/hello_project/bin/activate

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn’t exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn

# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use –daemon)
exec ~/.virtualenvs/hello_project/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
–name $NAME \
–workers $NUM_WORKERS \
–max-requests $MAX_REQUESTS \
–user=$USER –group=$GROUP \
–bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
–log-level=debug \
–log-file=$LOG_FILE
```

I am getting crazy here, there is no log file where I can look at, I even tried to create the socket file myself with no success. I suspect it's a permission problem but even when I run the script with sudo, it doesn't work.
My directory "run" gets created though.

Here is the nginx error from the error.log file:

```
2016/05/19 16:56:32 [crit] 11053#0: *28 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/git/hello_project/run/gunicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream...
```

Any clue ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

Try running the script without doing `exec ~/.virtualenvs/hello_project/bin/gunicorn`.

Instead try running it with `gunicorn` then the args.

This is assuming you have permission to install gunicorn on the system without a virtualenv.

I have a gist that starts the same process you're trying to run. (Django, Nginx, Gunicorn)
https://gist.github.com/marcusshepp/129c822e2065e20122d8

I see you're using `supervisor` so you're going to not want to use the `--deamon` option that I use in my script.